# Datatables, fixedHeader and header column click

Tags: datatables

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/mqapoxu8/4/

Table ordering is set to false, fixedHeader to true.

I intercept the column header click with

```
 $('.device-table').on( 'click', 'thead th', function () {
alert('x');
```

} );

It works fine except when the table has been scrolled.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from the official forums

```
$('.device-table thead').on( 'click', 'th', function () {
   alert('x');
} );
```